# open a file read lines break the string and write to a file in a different order PYTHON

Tags: python, string, split

I have a list in a file looks like this:

```
Adair, KY
Jackson, MS
Chicago, IL
ALASKA
```

I need to split the strings and re-write them to a new file like this:

```
KY:Adair
MS:Jackson
IL:Chicago
```

leaving out the state only names.

this is what I have so far:

```py
county_file = open("c:\\Python 3.8.3\\us-counties.2.txt", "r")
lines = county_file.readlines()
state_file = open("c:\\Python 3.8.3\\Ronnie.Vincent.County.Seats.manipulated.txt", "w")

for aline in lines:
    values = aline.split()
    print(values[1],':', values[0])
      
state_file.close()    
county_file.close()
```

I keep getting a 'list index out of range' error because the State only names do not have a values[1]. I can not figure out how to leave the state only names out. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm stuck.

Comment: could you use code blocks for code (and file content) to make it readable?

Comment: If this answer worked, you could accept it by checking the mark besides the answer.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to leave out the State only lines completly the simplest solution would be:

```py
for aline in lines:
  try: 
    values = aline.split() 
    print(values[1],':', values[0])
  except IndexError:
    print('skipping line', aline)
```

Comment: Sorry I'm completely green when it comes to programming. It gives me IndexOutOfRangeException not defined. Do I need to create a variable for it?

Comment: that was my bad, should be an IndexError not IndexOutOfRangeException. Fixed it in my answer.